# Apache webserver for MaxRequestWorkers

Tags: linux, apache, configuration, webserver

I am using Apache web server and I am testing my application using Apache benchmark (a tool to hit the http request concurrently), When I use till 300 concurrent requests it is succeeding but when It crosses 300. few requests are failing with ***SSL handshake failed (5)***. I understand that Apache web server has 256 request limitation, So I increased the MaxRequestWorkers to 1000 still I get the SSL handshake failure error for few request.

Could someone please check this configuration and let me know the issue in my environment.

***Configuration of Apache server:***

1) httpd version,

```
  # httpd -v

Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Oct 19 2017 20:39:16
```

2) I checked the status using the following command,

```
# systemctl status httpd -l

httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-03-07 23:46:32 IST; 1min 55s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 4351 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4359 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 264; Current requests/sec: 0.1; Current traffic: 204 B/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─4359 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4360 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─4362 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─5100 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─5386 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─5415 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─5416 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

3) Since the httpd is pointing to the path : /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service

```
vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service

[Unit]
Description=The Apache HTTP Server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Documentation=man:httpd(8)
Documentation=man:apachectl(8)

[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/httpd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful
ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID}
# We want systemd to give httpd some time to finish gracefully, but still want
# it to kill httpd after TimeoutStopSec if something went wrong during the
# graceful stop. Normally, Systemd sends SIGTERM signal right after the
# ExecStop, which would kill httpd. We are sending useless SIGCONT here to give
# httpd time to finish.
KillSignal=SIGCONT
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

4) As per the above command I found the env file is available '/etc/sysconfig/httpd'

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/httpd

#
# This file can be used to set additional environment variables for
# the httpd process, or pass additional options to the httpd
# executable.
#
# Note: With previous versions of httpd, the MPM could be changed by
# editing an "HTTPD" variable here.  With the current version, that
# variable is now ignored.  The MPM is a loadable module, and the
# choice of MPM can be changed by editing the configuration file
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf
#

#
# To pass additional options (for instance, -D definitions) to the
# httpd binary at startup, set OPTIONS here.
#
#OPTIONS=

#
# This setting ensures the httpd process is started in the "C" locale
# by default.  (Some modules will not behave correctly if
# case-sensitive string comparisons are performed in a different
# locale.)
#
LANG=C
```

5) As per the above command, I found that the conf fileis available in the path : /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf

vi /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf

```
# Select the MPM module which should be used by uncommenting exactly
# one of the following LoadModule lines:

# prefork MPM: Implements a non-threaded, pre-forking web server
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html
#LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so

# worker MPM: Multi-Processing Module implementing a hybrid
# multi-threaded multi-process web server
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html
#
LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so

# event MPM: A variant of the worker MPM with the goal of consuming
# threads only for connections with active processing
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/event.html
#
#LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
   ServerLimit 1000
   MaxRequestWorkers 1000
</IfModule>
```

What is wrong with my Apache configuration? Why it is not serving 1000 concurrent request? How to achieve more concurrent request in Apache web server?

Comment: While this link does not provide a solution, it may contain useful info: https://serverfault.com/questions/563412/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.